# Building A Referral System Using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

So am still kinda new to nodejs and am currently on a project and would to integrate a referral sytem into it. Basically on registering a user has a generated unique url that ither users can register with, i have gotten pass this part but now am trying to link the new user and the user who owns the link.

Here are my Models:
**Referral Model**

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';

const referralSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    referralId: [
        {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        }
    ],
    referralLink: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }

})

const Referral = mongoose.model("Referral", referralSchema);

export default Referral;
```

**User Model**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose'

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    emailToken: String,
    isVerified: Boolean,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    isAdmin: Boolean,
    refId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "referral",
    },
    walletId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "wallet",
    },
    plan: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "plan",
        }
    ]


})

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

And Here is my code

```
router.get('/verify-email', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ emailToken: req.query.token });
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'Token is invalid, Please contact us for assistance');
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        user.emailToken = null;
        user.isVerified = true;

        const savedUser = await user.save().then((user) => {
            //Create new referral for new user
            const newReferrer = new Referral({
                referralId: uuidv4(),
                referralLink: uuidv4(),
                userId: user._id,
            });
            //save referral to the database
            newReferrer.save()

            const customUserResponse = { user: savedUser }
            customUserResponse.refCode = newReferrer.referralId

            req.login(user, async (err) => {
                if (err)
                    return next(err);
                req.flash('success', `Welcome to Jenerouszy Mechanism ${user.username}`);
                const redirectUrl = req.session.redirectTo || `/dashboard`;
                delete req.session.redirectTo;
                res.redirect(redirectUrl);
            });

        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong, please try again or contact us for assistance')
        res.redirect('/')
    }
});
```

```
router.get("/referrals", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    Referral.findOne({ userId: req.user._id })
        .populate('user') //Populate model with user
        .then(loggedUser => {
            //Generate random referral link
            const generatedRefLink = `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}/register?reflink=${loggedUser.referralLink}/dashboard`
            res.render('dashboard/referrals', {
                loggedUser: loggedUser,
                generatedRefLink: generatedRefLink

            })
        })


})
```

I don't know how to go about this, can someone please guide me on what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by *link the new user and the user who owns the link*?

Comment: so in the user's dashboard I want to display everyone who registers through his/her link and implement a reward system

Comment: Ah! How about hashing the username/userid of the user who shared the link? For example, turning `KaiserKatze` into `612b01a3` and further into `http://shareme.com/register/612b01a3`? Then all you need is to store the mapping between the hash result and the username/userid, as well as the count of how many times ppl registered thru the link.